# Connected components of subspaces vs. space

Tags: general-topology

If $Y$ is a subspace of $X$, and $C$ is a connected component of $Y$, then C need not be a connected component of $X$ (take for instance two disjoint open discs in $\mathbb{R}^2$).

But I read that, under the same hypothesis, $C$ need not even be connected in $X$. Could you please provide me with an example, or point me towards one?

Thank you.

**SOURCE** http://www.filedropper.com/manifolds2 Page 129, paragraph following formula (A.7.16).

Comment: What do you mean by 'connected in $X$'? Connected viewed as a subspace of $X$?

Comment: connectedness is like compactness an intrinsic property: it does not matter how a subspace sits in a space.

Answer (score 3):

Isn't it just false? The image of a connected subspace by the injection $Y\longrightarrow X$ is connected...

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure you read correctly? Suppose $C$ is not connected in $X$. By definition this means that there exists two open sets $U, V\subset X$ such that $U\cap C \neq \emptyset$, $V\cap C\neq \emptyset$, $U\cap V = \emptyset$, and $C\subset U\cup V$. But then by definition of subspace topology, $U' = U\cap Y$ is open in $Y$, and $V' = V\cap Y$ is open in $Y$. And since $C\subset Y$, you have that $U' \cap V' = \emptyset$ and $C \subset U'\cup V'$, and $C \subset C\cap U \subset Y\cap U = U'$ etc. so $C$ cannot be connected in $Y$.

Comment: I'm probably wrong, but, how do you know that $U'$ and $V'$ are not empty?

Comment: @Weltschmerz: $C\subset Y$, and $C\cap U\neq \emptyset$ $\implies$ $C\cap U \subset Y\cap U = U' \neq \emptyset$.  And _mutatis mutandis_ for $V'$.

Comment: @Wille: right, thank you. I posted the source, if you're interested.

Comment: You need not to have $U \cap V = \emptyset$. What you need is $U \cap V \cap C = \emptyset$. See my "wrong" reply.